# question regards ways binary files are being viewed in c

Tags: c, binary, binaryfiles

I am studying for an interview and found this question a bit bewildering. Would appreciate your advise.

```
Suppose a person opens a binary file using a text editor. What is the correct claim regarding data stored in the file?
* "Can not be read by humans" means: A person will see gibberish ("nonsense").
* "Can be read by humans" means: A person can see the value that was in place and not gibberish.

1. Integers can be read by a person when characters are not readable by a person
2. Neither integers nor characters can be read by a human being
3. Both integers and characters can be read by a person if only integers or only characters are saved in a file but they are not readable if they appear in the file together
4. Both integers and characters can always be read by a human
5. Integers are not readable by a human being while characters are readable by a human being
```

I think the answer is #3 but not sure about the explanation..

Comment: Is it your intent to ask us about *every* one of these questions you're studying? So far, you've done three in the last hour with the same format: post question, state which you think is correct but not why, and ask for advice. You'll learn faster if you tell us *why* you think one is correct, so we can target our answers.

Comment: I have been studying and put on the side the questions I didn't know. Then I posted them on separate pages because the are about different subjects. Is there any problem?

Comment: No, it'll just be easier to target answers if you can state why you think the option is correct rather than just stating "seeking advice, not sure about the explanation". Obviously, there's *some* reason why you think your chosen one is correct. If we knew what it was, we could confirm or explain why your reasoning is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

5. Character data is text is human readable. Binary integer values will just show as garbage. Binary 41 hex == 0100 0001 binary == A ascii. In hex a 4 byte value of , say, 0D0A0D0A will show in the text as two blank lines. 7F is backspace (rub out). 08 is bell. And so on. Code pages and escape sequences and extended character sets, Intel vs network order, or even EBCDIC. TEXT editors show readable data. That is a rather small subset of what integer data encodes.